# trigger.io multiple developers best practices

Tags: version-control, trigger.io

Does anyone have recommendations for how to develop on the trigger.io platform with multiple developers?  We have an existing source code repository / code review process / staging process, and would like to share the trigger.io build system in a sane way as we foray into mobile.

In particular, we would like several developers to be able to use the build system, with the extra modules enabled when we paid for the service.

There doesn't appear to much documentation or support for this within this trigger.io system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for working in teams is actually a feature we have released recently. We just wrote a blog post that should be enough for you to get started with it: http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2013/01/15/introducing-projects/

If you have any feedback or run into any issues just ask here or send an email to support@trigger.io.